# H2 has a stretched width and I have no idea why

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm stumbling upon something really stupid but I want an image and a div to stretch on the 960px container (with flex justify content: space-between) in a row but the h2 takes up all the space of the remaining width, I have no idea why and can seem to find a way to fix it.

```css
.container-main{
  width: 96rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.activiteit{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.activiteit-title{
  font-family: "Fira Sans Heavy";
  font-size: 5rem;
}



.bg-activity{
  /* background-image: url(../assets/img/white-bg-small-lang-01.svg); */
  /* background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 40rem;
  width: 110rem; */
  background-position: center right;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

.activiteit-text{
  font-family: "Fira Sans Light";
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  line-height: 3.2rem;
}
```

```html
  <main>

    <div class="container-main">
      <article class="activiteit" id="activiteit1">
        <img src="./assets/img/C.svg" alt="C" width="400" height="400">
        <div class="bg-activity">

          <h2 class="activiteit-title">Blue Moonday.</h2>
          <p class="article-text">
            Als je er echt geen zin in hebt. Kruip dan terug in je bed. Neem je favoriete serie en snack en doe gewoon eens niets. Vergeet niet dat het tenslotte maar één maal blue monday per jaar is. Bekijk het positief er zijn zoveel meer mooie dagen. Check it
            out.
          </p>

        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </main>
```

Comment: You have a fixed width of `width: 96rem` and `h2` takes all it can have.

Comment: How can I fix that it just takes the space of the actual font-size and it doesn't take all the place?

Comment: @Vucko this is because by default, `h1`, `h2` etc. are `display:block`, which takes all the available width.

Comment: @LucasVerhoest use `display:inline` or something similar?

Comment: it's hard to figure out whether or not we're breaking something with only a small portion of the page (or is this all there is?)

Comment: I'll put the link of the site here

Comment: @LucasVerhoest from what i can tell here, not having `.bg-activity` use `display:flex` and making the `h2` `display:inline` keeps it from taking up all the available width.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it :( but is it okay to give it like a fixed width? That does seem to fix it but it looks like a bad work-around

Comment: @LucasVerhoest it's not pretty, no ;) i have a jsfiddle for you here, where i can see the contents of the `p` getting placed right behind the `h2`, by giving it a `float:left` rather than `display:inline` : https://jsfiddle.net/6nuuzezw/2/

Comment: Also, as a general warning : FexBox is a fickle beast, especially between different browsers. (i'm looking at you, IE/Edge). perhaps it's best to look for an alternative solution :)

Comment: Well actually I'm forced to work with flexbox from school they say that this is "the future". They are pushing really hard on this...

Comment: So hard that I shouldn't know how to do it with something else actually... Thanks for helping me out tho!

Comment: Was my answer useful?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not responding until now. I managed to fix it before your answer with a flex-wrap. I did check out yours too though! I really appreciate it for taking time to help me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have width of width: 96rem and h2 takes all it can have. you have you change it to something like 960px.

Comment: while it's true that the h2 takes all the available width, it'd be nice to know *why*, and also have a clearer solution than "set the width of something to something"

Answer (score 1):

The reason `justify-content: space-between;` has no effect on `activiteit` is because the `article-text` is wider than the available space left, hence force the `bg-activity` to fill the remaining space.

And as `bg-activity` is a flex column container, and as its `align-items` defaults to `stretch`, also the `activiteit` will fill its parent's width.

If you limit the width of the `.bg-activity` you will see what's going on.

*Note, I change some values/sizes to make it better show in a smaller container.*

Stack snippet

```css
.container-main{
  width: 800px; /*96rem;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.activiteit{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.activiteit-title{
  font-family: "Fira Sans Heavy";
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.bg-activity{
  background-position: center right;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.activiteit-text{
  font-family: "Fira Sans Light";
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  line-height: 3.2rem;
}

/*  added for demo purpose  */
.bg-activity{
  max-width: 500px;
}
.activiteit{
  background: #ddd;
}
.activiteit-title{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.bg-activity{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<main>

    <div class="container-main">
      <article class="activiteit" id="activiteit1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200/f00" alt="C" width="200" height="200">
        <div class="bg-activity">

          <h2 class="activiteit-title">Blue Moonday.</h2>
          <p class="article-text">
            Als je er echt geen zin in hebt. Kruip dan terug in je bed. Neem je favoriete serie en snack en doe gewoon eens niets. Vergeet niet dat het tenslotte maar één maal blue monday per jaar is. Bekijk het positief er zijn zoveel meer mooie dagen. Check it
            out.
          </p>

        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </main>
```

---

So if you e.g. want the text in the `activiteit-title` to appear to *right align*, which it would if not for the `article-text`, you could change the `align-items` on `bg-activity` to `flex-end`.

```css
.container-main{
  width: 800px; /*96rem;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.activiteit{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.activiteit-title{
  font-family: "Fira Sans Heavy";
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.bg-activity{
  background-position: center right;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.activiteit-text{
  font-family: "Fira Sans Light";
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  line-height: 3.2rem;
}
```

```html
<main>

    <div class="container-main">
      <article class="activiteit" id="activiteit1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200/f00" alt="C" width="200" height="200">
        <div class="bg-activity">

          <h2 class="activiteit-title">Blue Moonday.</h2>
          <p class="article-text">
            Als je er echt geen zin in hebt. Kruip dan terug in je bed. Neem je favoriete serie en snack en doe gewoon eens niets. Vergeet niet dat het tenslotte maar één maal blue monday per jaar is. Bekijk het positief er zijn zoveel meer mooie dagen. Check it
            out.
          </p>

        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </main>
```

---

Or set `text-align: right`  on `activiteit-title`.

```css
.container-main{
  width: 800px; /*96rem;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.activiteit{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.activiteit-title{
  font-family: "Fira Sans Heavy";
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: right;
}

.bg-activity{
  background-position: center right;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.activiteit-text{
  font-family: "Fira Sans Light";
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  line-height: 3.2rem;
}
```

```html
<main>

    <div class="container-main">
      <article class="activiteit" id="activiteit1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200/f00" alt="C" width="200" height="200">
        <div class="bg-activity">

          <h2 class="activiteit-title">Blue Moonday.</h2>
          <p class="article-text">
            Als je er echt geen zin in hebt. Kruip dan terug in je bed. Neem je favoriete serie en snack en doe gewoon eens niets. Vergeet niet dat het tenslotte maar één maal blue monday per jaar is. Bekijk het positief er zijn zoveel meer mooie dagen. Check it
            out.
          </p>

        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </main>
```